# Invalid Date for some UTC Strings Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, utc

Trying to get UTC day of the week for any given timestamp on any given machine (w/ their own local time) I used:

```
 var date = new Date(timestamp).toLocaleString('en-GB', { timeZone: 'UTC' });
```

Once I try to convert the *date* string to UTC date I get *Invalid Date* for some dates... it all seems pretty weird.

```
$ node
> date = new Date('15/08/2019, 00:00:00');
Invalid Date
> date = new Date('12/08/2019, 00:00:00');
2019-12-08T00:00:00.000Z
> date = new Date('15/08/2019');
```

Any idea where the Invalid Date issue may come from?

Comment: '15/08/2019, 00:00:00' is not a format supported by ECMA-262, so parsing is implementation dependent. You might get a correct parse, incorrect parse, or invalid date.

Comment: If you're looking for a UTC day, just [`getUTCDay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCDay).

Answer (score 0):

By converting the timestamps to strings using the "en-GB" locale, it looks like you're getting them in DD/MM/YYYY format.  But in your second example, the strings are being interpreted as "MM/DD/YYYY" in whatever your default locale is, so the first call fails because 15 isn't a valid month number.

Comment: "Default locale" is not relevant for parsing.